# Excel: convert unusual minute format into numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to analyze data from a application in Excel 2010. The application stores worked hours in a unusual way:

- 15 = 15 minutes
- 30 = 30 minutes
- 45 = 45 minutes
- 100 = 60 minutes / 1 hour
- 115 = 75 minutes / 1 hour 15 minutes
- 130 = 90 minutes / 1 hour 30 minutes
- ...
- 200 = 120 minutes / 2 hours
- ...

My desired output are minutes as numbers (15, 30, 45, 60, 75, ...), not in time format.
I am looking for a formula to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a combination of integer math and modulus.  `INT(A1/100)` will give the Hours, `MOD(A1,100)` will give the minutes.

```
       =INT(F3/100)*60+MOD(F3,100)
100    60
30     30
130    90
```